# How to Insert dot(.) again in textarea, if we have created a function to replace it?

Tags: javascript, html, html-entities, html-encode

I have created a  function to replace dot(.) into purnviraam, it works fine. but If we need to insert " . " again in textarea, I have created a button neart textarea with function. it inserts dot"." but pressing shift, it also converts in purnviraam. Please guide me, I don't have much knowledge of js coding.

```js
$(function() {
  $('textarea').on("keyup", function(e) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var str = val.replace('.', String.fromCharCode(2404));
    $(this).val(str);
  });
});


function myFunction1() {
  insertfullstop.data.value += '.';
  document.getElementById("data").focus();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="1">
      <form id="insertfullstop">
        <textarea type='text' id="data" class="js-copytextarea" style="width: 100%; max-width: 400px; height: 200px; border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;" name="data" autofocus="" placeholder="Start Type Here................"></textarea>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="right">
    <td style="padding-top: 5px; float='center' padding-left: 1px; " colspan="1">
      <strong style="font-size: 16px;"></strong>
      <button id="fullstop" OnClick="myFunction1()" class="btn1" title="Full Stop" type="button">.</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Show us the code here.

Comment: @Grumpy , Sir, I have added the code in the question

Comment: @Grumpy, Sir Please check the [link](https://xsajxbjkls.blogspot.com/2021/11/bm-lm.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you replace . with | on EVERY keyup event, which means that; you can add the dot with your function correctly but when you type the textarea it is going to replace the previously added dot with |

To solve this:
check if the typed character is a dot or not. If it is a dot, only then, replace it with a |. This way, it will not replace the previously added dot.

Comment: | is not equal to ।, we want to insert dot "."  in same textarea, whenever we need it

Comment: same logic applys. sorry if i have not been clear: what you do is this: you replace the dot with the above character EVERYTIME you type something. In order for your code to work as you want, you need to replace the dot ONLY if the character typed was a dot, and not each time a character is typed.

Comment: Please edit in the code